# Adding a searchBar to your TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, multidimensional-array, uisearchbar

I'd like to add search functionality to a `TableView` in my app. I populate a table with an `NSArray` which has `x` amount of `Objects` that contain 3 `NSStrings`. Here's how I construct that `NSArray`:

First I create a class `Code.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Code : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *codeName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *codeNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *codeDesc;

@end
```

Next, I synthesize these `NSStrings` in `Code.m`.

Now in my `SearchViewController.m`, Here's how I create my dataset:

```
NSMutableArray *codes;
codes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Code *c = [[Code alloc] init];
[c setCodeNumber:@"1"];
[c setCodeName:@"First Title Here"];
[c setCodeDesc:@"I might write a desc in here."];
[codes addObject:c];

c = [[Code alloc] init];
[c setCodeNumber:@"2"];
[c setCodeName:@"Second Title Here"];
[c setCodeDesc:@"2nd desc would be written here."];
[codes addObject:c];
```

and so on...

Here is how I display it: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 Code *c = [codes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString *fused = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[c codeNumber],[c codeName]];
 cell.textLabel.text = fused;
 return cell;
```

So now that you know how my data is structured and displayed, do you have an idea of how to search either the `NSArray` or possibly (preferably) the `TableCells` that have already been created?

I have been through the few tutorials online regarding `Adding a Search Bar to a TableView`, but all of them are written for using arrays setup using simple `arrayWithObjects`.

SIDETHOUGHT: Is it possible for me to construct an `arrayWithObjects:@"aaa-1",@"bbb-2",@"ccc-3"...` from my data? If i can manage that, I can use those tutorials to populate my cells and search them!

UPDATE:

Your second answer makes plenty more sense to me! Thanks for that. I beleive I have followed your instruction, but I am getting a "-[Code search:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2eb20` when that line is hit.

1. I added `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchString;` to `Code.h` and synthesized it in `Code.m`
2. I added `NSMutableSet *searchResults;` to `SearchViewController.h`'s `@interface`
3. I added your methods `performSearchWithString` and `matchFound` to `SearchViewController.m`
4. Directly under those I added this to call `performSearchWithString`

x

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchString {
NSLog(@"%@",searchString); //Just making sure searchString is set
[self performSearchWithString:searchString];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The error hits when `[codes makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(search:) withObject:self];` runs.  I am confused b/c it sounds like Code doesn't recognize searchString, but I know I added it in Code.h.

UPDATE:
In order to store objects in `searchResults`, I had to change `searchResults` from a `NSMutableSet` to a `NSMutableArray` and modify `- (void)matchFound:(Code *) matchingCode {}` to this:

```
-(void) matchFound:(Code *) matchingCode {

Code *match = [[Code alloc] init];

if (searchResults.count == 0) {
    searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [match setCodeName:[matchingCode codeName]];
    [match setCodeNumber:[matchingCode codeNumber]];
    [match setCodeDesc:[matchingCode codeDesc]];
    [searchResults addObject:match];
}
else
{
    match = [[Code alloc] init];
    [match setCodeName:[matchingCode codeName]];
    [match setCodeNumber:[matchingCode codeNumber]];
    [match setCodeDesc:[matchingCode codeDesc]];
    [searchResults addObject:match];

}
```

With a few other tweeks, I've got a working searchbar for my tableView. Thanks Tim Kemp!

Oh, also case insensitive search was what I was looking for. `NSRange rangeName = [codeName rangeOfString: searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

I hope this question and answer will be helpful to the next developer learning objective-c with this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simpler approach**

You asked for a simpler solution. This one isn't nearly as flexible, but it will achieve the same things as my earlier answer for this specific case.

Once again we are going to ask `Code` to search its strings for us. This time, we are going to skip the `SearchRequest` and the block callback and implement it directly.

In your `SearchViewController` you will create two methods. One to do the search, and one callback to process any results as they come back. You will also need a container to store matching `Code` objects (more than one might match, presumably.) You will also need to add a method to `Code` to tell it what the search string is.

1. Add an ivar `NSMutableSet` called `searchResults` to `SearchViewController`.
2. Add a property of type `NSString *` called `searchString` to `Code`
3. Add the search method to `SearchViewController`. This is what you'll call when you want to initiate a search across all your codes:

   ```
   -(void) performSearchWithString:(NSString *) searchString {
      // Tell each Code what string to search for
      [codes makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setSearchString:) withObject:searchString];
      // Make each code perform the search
      [codes makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(search:) withObject:self];
    }
   ```
4. Then you will also need a callback in `SearchViewController`. This is so that your `Code` objects can tell the `SearchViewController` that they have found a match:

   ```
   -(void) matchFound:(Code *) matchingCode {
     [searchResults addObject:matchingCode];
     // do something with the matching code. Add it to a different table 
     // view, or filter it or whatever you need it to do.
   }
   ```

However do note that you don't *have* to use the `searchResults` mutable set; you may well want to just call another method to immediately add the returned result to some other list on screen. It depends on your app's needs.

In `Code`, add a search method a bit like we had before, but instead of the `SearchRequest` parameter we'll pass in a reference to the `SearchViewController`:

```
    - (void) search:(SearchViewController *) searchVC {
      // Search each string in turn
      NSRange rangeNum = [codeNumber rangeOfString : searchString];
      NSRange rangeName = [codeName rangeOfString : searchString];
      NSRange rangeDesc = [codeDesc rangeOfString: searchString];
      if (rangeNum.location != NSNotFound || rangeName.location != NSNotFound || rangeDesc.location != NSNotFound) {
         [searchVC matchFound:self];
      }
    }
```

Do you see how that works? If there's a match in any of the strings (`||` means 'or') then pass `self` (which means exactly what it sounds like: the current object that's running this code right now) back to a method in the view controller called `searchVC`. This is called a *callback* because we are "calling back" to the object which originally sent us the message to do the search. We have to use callbacks rather than simple return types because we have used `makeObjectsPerformSelector` to tell every single `Code` in the `codes` array to do a search. We never explicitly called the `search` method ourselves, so we have no way to capture the return value from each `search`. That's why its return type is `void`.

You can extend `matchFound` to take an additional parameter which identifies which string the match was in (i.e. `çodeNumber`, `codeName` or `codeDesc`.) Look into `enums` as one good approach to pass around that kind of data.

Hope that's bit simpler.

[Here is a link to an excellent language introduction/tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) which will eliminate much confusion.

*EDIT* In your last comment you said that `searchResults` was null. I said to add it as an ivar somewhere in `SearchViewController`. In your initialiser method for SearchViewController you should call

```
searchResults = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:50]` // Choose some sensible number other than 50; enough to hold the likely number of matching Code objects.
```

Alternatively you could 'lazy initialise' it in `matchFound`:

```
- (void) matchFound:(Code *) matchingCode {
  if (!searchResults)
    searchResults = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:50];

  [searchResults addObject:matchingCode];
}
```

Though if you do this you should be aware that anywhere else you access `searchResults` may find that it's null if `matchCode:` has never previously been called.

Comment: I've updated my question to show where I'm at with your 2nd answer. I looks like Code doesn't recognize search:self as a selector with object

Comment: Did you write `search` as a method in `Code`? Did you also add it to the interface (i.e. `code.h`?)

Comment: No and no, I've now added `- (void) search;` to `Code.h`, but i'm unsure of how to write it as a method in `Code.m`... `- (void) search{}`? I used that code, but I still get the same error. I'm writing it incorrectly.

Comment: In `Code.h` the method signature should be `- (void) search:(SearchViewController *) searchVC;` then you can just paste the method body in my answer above into `Code.m` Have a read of the link that I've edited into the answer: it will make a lot of this much clearer. Again sorry if I'm confusing you with any of this.

Comment: Please also note that you will need to make the following changes: In `Code.h` add a line `@class SearchViewController` *before* the `@interface Code` line; and then in `Code.m` add an `#import "SearchViewController.h" next to the other imports. This is so that you can reference the view controller from the view, and vice versa.

Comment: I've added an overlay to the tableview while searching, and a 'Done' button to close the search keyboard, all works well. But I run into a problem when a match is found and added to `searchResults`. Immediately before that line I put an `NSLog` to display in the console the contents of `matchingCode`. It does display a location in memory for each match found, but when I run an `NSLog` directly after `[searchResults addObject:matchingCode];` to display `searchResults`, it returns `null`. I don't understand how it's empty when we just added a bunch of matches to it.

Comment: @Paul, I expect that you did not `alloc` or `init` your `searchResults` set. See edited answer.

Comment: You're right, I was not allocating searchResults, but I figured this out a few days ago. I posted an UPDATE on my post showing what I was missing incase others might benefit from this question. Thanks a ton for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Original, flexible and more complicated answer**

I'm a little unclear as to what you're trying to do, so I'm going with your title, "Searching each string in each object of an array." In your case, your `Code`s have three strings and your array has multiple `Code`s. I assume that you need a way to tell the caller - the code that wants to do the search - which `Code` matches.

Here is one approach. There are easier ways but this technique is quite flexible. Broadly, we are going to make the `Code` object do the work of searching its own strings. We are then going to give the `Code` object the ability to tell the caller (i.e. the object that owns the `codes` array, presumably your table view controller) whether any of its strings match the search string. We will then use `NSArray`'s method `makeObjectsPerformSelector` to have to tell all of its `Code` objects to search themselves. We will use a block for a callback.

Firstly, add a `search` method to `Code` (in the interface, or as a category depending on your design), something like this:

```
-(void) search:(SearchRequest *) request {
  // Search using your favourite algorithm
  // eg bool matches = [searchMe [request searchString]];
  if (matches) {
    [request foundMatch:self];
  }
}
```

`SearchRequest` is new. It's a place to tie together a search string and a callback block. It looks something like this:

```
@interface SearchRequest
@property (retain) NSString * searchString;
@property (copy) void (^callback)(Code *);
- (id) initWithSearchString:(NSString *) search callback:(void (^)(Code *)) callback;
- (void) foundMatch:(Code *) matchingCode;
@end

@implementation SearchRequest
// synthesize...
// initialiser sets ivars
- (void) foundMatch:(Code *) matchingCode {
  callback(matchingCode);
}
```

The `callback` block is our way of communicating back to the caller.

When you want to perform a search, construct a `SeachRequest` object with the string you're searching for and a block which contains the method to call when you get a match.
That would look like this, in the caller:

```
- (void) performASearchWithString:(NSString *) searchForMe {
    SearchRequest * req = [[SearchRequest alloc] initWithSearchString:searchForMe 
                                     callback:^(Code * matchingCode) {
                                                  [self foundAHit:matchingCode];
                                     }];

    [codes makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(search:) withObject:req];
}
```

You then need to implement `foundAHit` in your caller, which takes the matching `Code` and does something with it. (You don't have to use a block: you could store a reference to the caller and a selector to call on it instead. I won't go into the arguments for either case here. Other answerers can propose alternatives.)

Comment: This is a bit above my skill level, with some time I'll work through it though, I appreciate your help. I'll report back to you after some time.

Comment: Apologies. There are less complicated ways of achieving your goal; I'll write something up over the weekend.